# Passing a simple string to my EJS template gives undefined in a working app

Tags: node.js, templates, ejs

So I needed to add some more information for my users and as a test I'd try to pass a simple string to my view, you know just to get it going. My app worked before I added this change.

Before I sent this to my ejs template:

```
   if (errorMessage) {
      res.render("index", {weather: null, error: errorMessage})
    } else {        

      res.render("index",{weather:weatherText, error:null});
    }
```

My weather is simply a string containing information but nothing but a string. 
I then tried to add this little string to my rendering:

```
res.render("index",{weather:weatherText, error:null, testStr: "Hello"});
```

Calling it:

```
<%= testStr %>
```

but my testStr is undefined. Anyone has an idea what causes this, to me it's the exact same as the weather which works wonder.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what caused it. Wasn't using nodemon, a server restart solved it.